# Rebuilding a full text index in a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a requirement to have a full text index on  SQL Server table, where the customer wants the index to be updated as soon as a record is updated.  I figured the best bet could we to add this trigger on the table...

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Section_InsUpd ON dbo.[Section] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS

ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG TUG REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF

GO
```

But when this is triggered I'm told I can't rebuild the catalog in a user transaction.  Can anyone tell me how to achieve my objective?  A scheduled index rebuild every couple of minutes seems like a bad idea as the table won't be updated very often, but when it is, they want the changes available in the full text index as soon as possible.

Comment: **Don't do this!** Seriously - you should **never** have any time-consuming activities in a trigger.... a good trigger just makes a note of something - but it definitely should not be doing any time-consuming work!

Comment: Totally appreciate your point marc_s, but in this case it's definitely not intensive as it'll contain at most a few hundred records which will very rarely change, currently the rebuild of the index is taking <0.1 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an update table, for example:

> CREATE TABLE IndexUpdates (TableName NVARCHAR(255), UpdateIndex BIT)

Have your trigger update the relevant entry to 1. Now have a job that runs every minute or two, looking at whether or not the table has been updated and have the job rebuild the index. On completion, reset the UpdateIndex to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Create the FULLTEXT indexing with AUTO change tracking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX on myTable (myColumn) WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO)
```

Works great and no triggers.